# Bootstrap 5: How to stop Carousel from moving to top of page on load?

Tags: html, carousel, bootstrap-5

I started putting the basic pieces together for my website and noticed the carousel keeps loading to the top of the page. When doing an example during class I had them same issue but didn't think much about it since the carousel was already at the top. In my design, this definitely is annoying. Is there a way to prevent this?

I've tried searching for the past 30min but I can't find a similar question asked anywhere.

Example video here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wlYB18xmMrmIKWY2TbbUc-x78s6VYH0L/view?usp=sharing

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-indicators">
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="images/carousel-readingzone.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="images/carousel-mathzone.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="images/carousel-creativezone.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I tested your code with bootstrap 5. I had no problems. I'm not sure what the problem is with this part of the code (but I could be wrong). Are you using custom jquery?

Comment: Your video shows you're loading index.html#carouselExampleIndicators. The #carouselExampleIndicators will position the tag with the id carouselExampleIndicators at the top. What happens if you load your page with just 127.0.0.1:5500/index.html?

Comment: Oh my god the #carouselExampleIndicators was it. I was going to say I felt completely stumped because I couldn't find anything in the code that would have caused that. Not sure why or how that got added on to the url, but it seems like visual studio code automatically puts that there when I load the live preview.